# Logo for Robotics SE?

Tags: discussion, support

I was wondering how the logos work on SE? Do you guys think having a logo for the robotics page would help? seeing that some of the other pages have their own unique logos like stack overflow, mathematics or even Physics. Is there anyway we can push for that because I think having a logo of our own will add character to the page and to come extent help with promotion.

Comment: see also (What should our theme and layout look like?)[http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8/131]

Comment: http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-logo-should-we-use-after-beta-phase

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that whilst we are in Beta we get little say on the layout.

Once a site "graduates" it can gain a CSS skin (and a logo) all of its own.